# Nagios plugin: why does check_http -v add odd numbers between html output?

Tags: https, monitoring, nagios

Simple question, where I already spent hours searching for an answer:
The following HTTP check doesn't work, despite it's validity can be proven:
`./check_http --sni -H www.wikimedia.de -u /ueber-uns/ -S -s "cli-privacy-readmore"`

Verify this with a visit to the source code and search for it: https://www.wikimedia.de/ueber-uns/.

The verbose switch gives more insight, though that's where I'm at the end of my knowledge:

```
> ./check_http --sni -H www.wikimedia.de -u /ueber-uns/ -S -s "cli-privacy-readmore" -v | grep cli-privacy-rea -A2 -n
1348:                <a class="cli-privacy-rea
1349-3000
1350-dmore" data-readmore-text="Zeig mehr" data-readless-text="Zeige weniger"></a>            </div>
```

Why is there a 3000 (on line 1349) in it? I've already found out that it's HEX and somehow used for length estimation. But neither a look inside tcpdump (the value is somehow transmitted, or added afterwards to the packets), nor the test with other variables (other gateway, os, site) brings me closer to a solution.

Can anyone help me?

Edit:

Tested on:

- Archlinux check_http v2.3 (monitoring-plugins 2.3)
- Ubuntu 18.04 check_http v2.2 (monitoring-plugins 2.2)

Comment: What is the output of that check? What exactly does not work?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I've been able to reproduce this a number of times on various sites that I monitor. In my case, it's generally showing 2000, which is hex for 8192, which seems to be the standard chunk size for http/1.1 on Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not reproducible.

```
# check_http --version
check_http v2.3.3 (nagios-plugins 2.3.3)
```

```
# check_http --sni -H www.wikimedia.de -u /ueber-uns/ -S -s "cli-privacy-readmore" -v | grep cli-privacy-rea -A2 -n
1340:                <a class="cli-privacy-readmore" data-readmore-text="Zeig mehr" data-readless-text="Zeige weniger"></a>            </div>
1341-        </div>
1342-        <div class="cli-col-12 cli-align-items-stretch cli-px-0 cli-tab-section-container">
```

```
# check_http --sni -H www.wikimedia.de -u /ueber-uns/ -S -s "cli-privacy-readmore"
HTTP OK: HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 95466 bytes in 0.375 second response time |time=0.375144s;;;0.000000 size=95466B;;;0
```

Try a newer version of the plugin.

**edit:** You also may not need to use a Nagios plugin for this as it's a pretty basic use case, unless you need the perfdata or similar you can just do this:

```
# curl --silent https://www.wikimedia.de/ueber-uns/ | grep -q "cli-privacy-readmore" ; echo $?
0

# curl --silent https://www.wikimedia.de/ueber-uns/ | grep -q "banana" ; echo $?
1
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint with using curl. I guess I'll stick with that.
I think you are right. The result is not very reproducible. After your answer I checked the website again and it seems something has changed. The numbers in the text have moved. If you look through the output of check_http -v you'll notice them.